# Maven vs. Gradle (scope) / spring-boot JUnit5

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit

I'm currently trying to implement JUnit5 Tests for my spring-boot rest services. I also found a promising tutorial, but I'm running into an error.

Tutorial: https://howtoprogram.xyz/2017/09/12/junit-5-spring-boot-example/

Compared to the tutorial, I'm using Gradle. My gradle looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0"
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
        exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")

    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0")

    // reroute default logs
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3"
    // json logs:
    compile "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:4.9"

    // junit
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0")
    // junit for spring-boot
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.5.7.RELEASE")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")//:1.5.7.RELEASE")
    {
        // exclude JUnit 4 support
        exclude group: "junit"
    }
    testCompile("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.0.0-M5")
    testCompile("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.0-M5")
}
```

I can't find out how to apply Maven script's test to my gradle script.

Also I'm getting these errors when building

```
/home/udev/prj/research/java-unittest/src/test/java/one/utest/HelloControllerTest.java:6: error: package org.springframework
.test.context.junit.jupiter does not exist
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
                                                     ^
/home/udev/prj/research/java-unittest/src/test/java/one/utest/HelloControllerTest.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
 ^
  symbol: class SpringBootTest
/home/udev/prj/research/java-unittest/src/test/java/one/utest/HelloControllerTest.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
   private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
           ^
  symbol:   class TestRestTemplate
  location: class HelloControllerTest
/home/udev/prj/research/java-unittest/src/test/java/one/utest/HelloControllerTest.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
            ^
  symbol: class SpringExtension
/home/udev/prj/research/java-unittest/src/test/java/one/utest/HelloControllerTest.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
   @Autowired
    ^
  symbol:   class Autowired
  location: class HelloControllerTest
5 errors
:compileTestJava FAILED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tutorial talks about spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, but you use version 1.5.7.RELEASE. In that version there is no Junit 5 support yet.

I'm unsure what you mean by `Maven script's test`, but if you mean the scope test, then in Gradle you just use `testCompile` or `testRuntime` to get the same effect.

Comment: Ahhh my bad... When I saw 2.0 i somehow read 1.2 and though this is an older version... Anyhow, I'm not able to fetch the version 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
Is there a special way to fetch versions that have the BUILD-SNAPSHOT postfix?

Yes, Maven script's test I meant the scope - OK, now it's clear what the "scope" means. Thanks!

Comment: Snapshot releases are not allowed on maven central, you need to define the repository where those builds are available. At https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ you find the needed repo, even in Gradle format, depending on whether you want to use a snapshot or a milestone build.